# How can I manipulate CSS animations with JavaScript to match a 'moving-box' with dynamic tiles in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi I have a problem with my css animation. I can't match the "moving-box" with the tiles that he is covering. I'm using bootstrap so the values in css can't be static so I thought about using JS but I have no idea how to inject js values into keyframes.
Here's the animation:

```
@keyframes slide {

0% {
  left: 0%;
  background: red;
}

25%{
  left: 26%;
  background: blue;

}
50%{
  left: 52%;
  background: yellow;

}
75%{
  left: 75%;
  background: purple;
}
100%{
  left: 95%;
  background: purple;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  
}
```

Here is the whole code:

https://codepen.io/squezer123/pen/JjmVNeN

I thought about using only css but I don't know what to use to accomplish that effect. I heard that this may be possible with react but I'm not sure.